# WhatsApp URL scheme Objective C share location

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, share, whatsapp

i searched a lot today to share a location in my iOS App via WhatsApp. It's possible to send text with the WhatsApp URL scheme (https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013), but does anyone knows if i can edit text in my WA-message or how i can get such an entry with map and adress? http://www.whatsapp.com/img/2.jpg

If anyone knows a solution it would be so nice :)

Comment: Per the documentation you linked, it's not possible.

Comment: Yeah i know, but google gets it via their website. They know how :D i hope maybe its just a different keyword like "whatsapp://send?location*" or something like this. Does anyone know?